# I have one Friend that said he is getting texts from me but its not me

Tags: phishing, sms

A friend of mine is getting a text asking him to click on a link to view a video.  The name is my first and last name.  Most people do not spell their first name as mine but there is no phone number and the email address shows up under "other".  I googled the email address and the email address belongs to a teacher in Texas.  I only have one friend that notified me of this.  So who is hacked? Him, Me or the Teacher?

Comment: Similar to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121175/how-does-sms-spoofing-work-practically https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19730/how-can-sms-spoofing-be-detected https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118429/how-can-someone-spoof-texts-with-my-phone-number

Comment: Quite possible that no one is hacked. It's easy to sent texts and have them say it comes from anyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does SMS spoofing work practically?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121175/how-does-sms-spoofing-work-practically)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to send a text message to a phone via almost any Email service.

There are email to SMS gateways for each provider, and there is a specific email suffix for each provider. For example, to text a number `1234567890` that happened to be an ATT number, you would send an email to `1234567890@txt.att.net`.

People can change their name in email services to whatever they wish, so it appears they are simply sending an email with your name entered in the email service configuration. The phone takes that name information and displays it along with the text message. It appears that this is simply an email to SMS message, and not an SMS spoof which would display an actual phone number and not an email address.